# How can i redirect in react core 3.1 template in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, react-redux

I'm using C# Core 3.1 React template in visual studio 2019.the problem is redirect is not working as expected in below code. How can I solve this issue?

```
return <Redirect to='/login'  />
```

Comment: Did you tried this one `<Route path="/login" component={yourcomponent} />`

Comment: yes, but <Redirect> not worked for me.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {
    let history = useHistory();

    //button event
    const SubmitLogin = async (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        history.push('/'); //redirect to home page
    }

    return (
            //your HTML return code here
        );
};

export default connect()(Login);
```